# Android develop hotspot local ip

Tags: java, android, jvm-hotspot

On newer android phones, you can just make a Hotspot for other users.
So if you open a hotspot, you will get a local ip adress like a 
switch or something equals ( 192.168.1.1 )
I want the local ip of the opened hotspot, how can i get it?
This one didn't worked, it returned 0.0.0.0 :

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by Voicu's answer returning a "public" IP.  Are you saying it returns the IP of the (upstream facing) mobile network interface?  Does it normally do that, if you are not in hotspot mode?

Comment: exactly. But I need the local ip of the hotspot I opened, mostly something like 192.168.xx.xx

Comment: You can try looking through /proc/net but the specifics of what you find may vary from implementation to implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
WifiManager wim = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
ipAddress.setText(Formatter.formatIpAddress(wim.getConnectionInfo()
    .getIpAddress()));
```

Comment: sorry but where is the difference between mines and yours??